Motivation for Hartshorne's formula for the $j$-invariant
On p. 317 of [1], Hartshorne (and he is not the only one) conjures the $j$-invariant of an elliptic curve out of the blue
\begin{equation*}
    j=2^8\frac{(\lambda^2-\lambda+1)^3}{\lambda^2(\lambda-1)^2}
\end{equation*}
where $\lambda$ is the parameter in the Legendre-form of the equation of the given elliptic curve. I know that $\lambda$ is the cross ratio of the four branch points when representing the given elliptic curve as a twofold branched cover of the projective line and that the above expression is cooked up in just the way given above as to make the different possible values of the cross ratio obtained by permuting the branch point by an automorphism unique, but is there a nice way to motivate the given form of it?
[1] Hartshorne, R. ― Algebraic Geometry, Graduate Texts in Mathematics 52, Springer 1977.

See section 19.9.7. The cross-ratio and the j-invariant (p. 557) of Vakil's The Rising Sea. The basic idea is to take the second elementary symmetric polynomial in $\lambda, 1 - \lambda, \frac{1}{\lambda}, 1 -\frac{1}{\lambda}, \frac{1}{1-\lambda}, 1 - \frac{1}{1 - \lambda}$. This isn't quite the $j$-invariant, but it generates the same field.

As I mentioned in the comments, $\S19.9.7$ The cross-ratio and the j-invariant (p. 557) of Vakil's The Rising Sea covers this topic in detail. Here's a summary.
An elliptic curve $E$ admits a degree $2$ map $x: E \to \mathbb{P}^1$, which has $4$ ramification values. Over an algebraically closed field $k$, one can map $3$ of the $4$ points to $0, 1, \infty$ by a Möbius transformation. The last ramification point is mapped to some $\lambda$ (which turns out to be the cross-ratio of the $4$ points), yielding a curve in Legendre form:
\begin{equation} \tag{$\ast$} \label{eqn}
y^2 = x(x-1)(x-\lambda) \, .
\end{equation}
However, there is still an action of $S_3$ permuting $0, 1, \infty$, under which $\lambda$ has orbit
$$
O_{\lambda} = \left\{\lambda, 1 - \lambda, \frac{1}{\lambda}, 1 -\frac{1}{\lambda}, \frac{1}{1-\lambda}, 1 - \frac{1}{1 - \lambda}\right\} \, .
$$
So we can replace $\lambda$ by any element of $O_\lambda$ in (\ref{eqn}) to get a different equation, but the curves are all isomorphic. Since the $j$-invariant classifies elliptic curves up to isomorphism, it should be invariant under this $S_3$-action, i.e., $j(t)$ must be the same for all $t \in O_\lambda$.
This suggests trying one of the elementary symmetric polynomials evaluated at the elements of $O_\lambda$. The sum and product of the elements in $O_\lambda$ are invariant, but turn out to be constant. So instead we try the second elementary symmetric polynomial, which yields
$$
j'(\lambda) = \frac{\lambda^6 - 3 \lambda^5 + 5 \lambda^3 - 3 \lambda + 1
}{\lambda^2 (\lambda - 1)^2} \, .
$$
This isn't quite the usual definition of the $j$-invariant, but it's close: they both generate the field of $S_3$-invariants $k(\lambda)^{S_3}$. In fact, we have
$$
2^8 j' + j = 2^9 \cdot 3 \implies j' = 6 - \frac{j}{2^8} \, .
$$
I think the reason the usual formula the $j$-invariant is preferred might be because of the ramification of the $j$-map. $j$ is ramified at the fixed points of the $S_3$-action (and $\infty$), two of which are the primitive $6^\text{th}$ roots of unity, which have minimal polynomial $t^2 - t + 1$ and are thus invariant under $t \mapsto 1 - \frac{1}{t}$. The usual formula for $j(\lambda)$ "aligns" these ramification points so that they are also zeroes of $j$.
